# dijit.form.NumberSpinner arrows on IE6

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo

When using the dijit.form.NumberSpinner widget, the arrow buttons don't show up on IE6,
unless I throw a lot of alert()s during init.

It seems they don't get rendered (properly)

Any ideas?

PS. I'm using dojo 1.3.2 with the tundra theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/9712